# Implement something that has both enum and class behavior

Tags: c++, class, c++11, enums

Consider that I have some 'thing' that has both enum and class behavior. As an example, consider a world which has the concept of Color, there are exactly 3: Red, Green and Blue.

Based on this color, we also have functionality, for example we could have a function which tells us whether a Color is a happy Color or not, and some other functions:

```
isHappy: Color -> {yes, no}
intensity: Color -> value
rotate: Color -> Color
```

To complete the haskel-like syntax, we could do this:

```
data Color = Red | Green | Blue
```

and implement the functions mentioned above. But that is haskell, which is not C++ and which has no notion of OO like c++ has. Continuing in C++:

The fact that we have exactly 3 colors, and no more, suggest the use of an enum; allowing us to use constants like red, blue and green anywhere in the source code. However, we cannot add methods to an enum, so isHappy intensity and rotate would be implemented as functions (and not methods).

The fact that we have these methods where the first parameter is a Color, suggest the use of a class. However, then we could instantiate as many of such classes as we'd like, especially more than 3. This means that two variables representing Red, will be allocated at different locations in memory. This is a bit strange, as Red will have very 'constant-like' behavior since it is immutable and only three different types of Color objects can be created. Moreover, we cannot use symbols like Red, Green and Blue, but would need to store them in variables. Using global variables would be very ugly imho.

We could also use inheritance, where Red, Green and Blue inherit from a Color class. This allows us to fine tune the functionality very easily, since we can implement what we want in whatever class we want. However, OO with inheritance in c++ applies slicing. For example, it would be very tricky to create a vector containing a list of (Red, Green or Blue)'s. Or to create a variable storing one of the 3 colors:

```
Color c1 = Red();
Color c2 = Blue();
```

The variables c1 and c2 will be assigned a different object, but there is no way to really distinct them. This makes implementing operator== tricky:

```
class Red : Color { //...
  bool operator==(Color &c) const{
     // no way to determine whether c is Red, Green or Blue.
  }
}
```

Is there a valid pattern or solution for this situation? I think it appears a lot, hence I am very curious. C++14-only solutions are also very much appreciated!

**EDIT**: Many people seem to comment that the problems for the solutions that I mention are not really problems. That is a valid point. However, I'm not looking for a possible solution, I'm looking for a solution which is according to a good c++(11|14) design principles. I could also use:

```
#define RED 0
#define GREEN 1
#define BLUE 2
```

And that would work perfectly fine, however it is not a good design principle as it may collide with other functionality, using names like RED, BLUE or GREEN. This is also semantically strange, since I could say RED

Summarizing, in the answer I would like to see a solution adhering to good c++ design principles. I don't care for solutions that just work! This could be one of the three previously mentioned ways, using an enum, one class or inheritance.

**EDIT2:** Meanwhile I also though of a template based approach for the multiple-inheritance case. However, to be fairly honest, my knowledge of templates is not adequate yet to create something 'good'. The idea is based on functions like std::is_same and std::is_functional of the type_traits header.

```
#include <iostream>

class Color {};

class Red : Color {};
class Green : Color {};
class Blue : Color {};

template<class C1, class C2>
bool is_same_color();

template<class C1>
bool is_happy();

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

It is not working, but I hope the idea get's across. Also, I realize is_same_color and is_happy should be classes with a operator() defined.

**EDIT3:** One could state that this is what I want:

```
enum Color {
  RED, GREEN, BLUE
  bool isHappy() { return this==GREEN || this==RED; }
  Color rotate() { return (this==RED ? GREEN (this==GREEN ? BLUE : RED)); }
  int intensity() { return (this==RED ? 11 (this==GREEN ? 12 : 4)); }
}
```

But that is of course, not valid c++.

Comment: I don't see any pressing reason why those can't be free functions and have to "be OO", whatever that means.

Comment: In other words, if you provided the code in Java first as an example, I could say "But that is Java, which is not C++ and which has no notion of OO like c++ has."

Comment: Maybe have a `Color` class with an embedded enumeration for the color, and have the `Red`, `Blue` etc. functions that create an appropriate object. Mix this with some operator overloads (like e.g. `operator==`) and it might do what you want?

Comment: Regarding "be OO": I don't state that they can't be, but in general I think it is good practice to reconsider using methods if you have a lot of function_X(Class_Y p1, other params). Would you disagree? The difference with Java would be that C++ slices objects that are assigned to a super-class variable. I'm not stating that's bad, just that this makes it trickier to create 'something' for Color. Also note that the reason I'm asking this is because I don't know what a good practice is, hence providing one is hard.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Are you suggesting this: http://ideone.com/sQfUtf

Comment: *"This means that two variables representing Red, will still have red1 == red2 evaluate to false."*  ... why exactly?

Comment: @Herbert Something like that yes.

Comment: @Nawaz: assuming one does not overload the == operator. The point is that the behavior doesn't come natural, like with enum's.

Comment: @Herbert Assuming you don't implement some functionality, you won't have that functionality. That is hardly a relevant design point of view. You're asking how to design stuff so that it behaves the way you want. C++ allows you to overload `operator ==`, therefore you should consider that doable.

Comment: @Angew: It makes sense that one needs to implement behavior, yet I think it makes more sense to choose the right design to minimize implementation of trivial operation. Of course, one can not prevent that things need to be explicitly implemented, I get that. IE: the standard containers were designed such that implementation takes O(N+M) for N container types and M algorithms, instead of O(M*N). I'm looking for the same thing, a solution that is a 'smart' choice.

Comment: @Herbert: If you don't overload `==`, then still I'm unable to understand why `red1 == red2` would evaluate to `false`? C++ isn't that stupid. It'd result in compilation error.

Comment: Red is a constant value, not a class. Color might be a class.

Comment: @CashCow I agree that Red could very well be a constant value, how would you implement that?

Comment: @Nawaz : You are right, however my point that the ==-functionality is not there naturally stays. So my question stays: which one is better c++ design: an enum with functions or a class with methods? (or something else)

Comment: I'm confused : how can you have 2 instances of red ? If red is indeed a color, then there is only one Red. Red can be an instance of class color. I think you are looking a for a perfect implementation of a flawed concept.

Comment: @FélixCantournet: You could call the constructor creating a Color object representing red twice. See anton-savin 's implementation, where contructors are made private to prevent this. Why is what concept flawed?

Comment: *"This means that two variables representing Red, will be allocated at different locations in memory. [...] Red will have very 'constant-like' behavior since it is immutable"* The C++ object model is basically this: There are values, which are immutable, and objects, which store values. You can change which value a certain object stores, but you cannot change the value itself. This is how `int` works, and the number/value `42` represents is as immutable as the color/value `Red` represents. The objects don't represent the value, they *contain the value*. The set of valid `int`s is also finite.

Comment: Ultimately you have to look at your use cases. If you want `Color` to behave like a type in C++ and no existing types fit your needs, then make it a class and write it to fit your needs. If you want `Color` to behave like an existing type such as an `enum` then put it in a `namespace` with corresponding functions. Do whatever best suits your needs, not whatever someone else told you is the 'right' way of doing something.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a class and use specific instances (a la singleton) for the `enum`:

```
class Color
{
public:
    bool isHappy() const { return this == &Green || this == &Red; }
    const Color* rotate() const { return (this == &Red ? &Green : (this == &Green ? &Blue : &Red)); }
    int intensity() const {return mIntensity; }

    static const Color* red() { return &Red; }
    static const Color* green() { return &Green; }
    static const Color* blue() { return &Blue; }

private:
    // forbid to construct new instance: use only red(), green(), blue()
    explicit Color(int intensity) : mIntensity(intensity) {}
    Color(const Color&) = delete; 
private:
    int mIntensity;

private:
    static const Color Red;
    static const Color Green;
    static const Color Blue;
};

const Color Color::Red(11);
const Color Color::Green(12);
const Color Color::Blue(4);
```

Comment: Nicely done, but still the need to use pointers when put in a std container, since to the best of my knowledge they cannot contain references.

Comment: @Herbert: You may play with `std::reference_wrapper` instead of pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Some other nice answers have been given, but I am afraid they don't use the C++ expression and clarity and conciseness to the full extent.

I propose the following solution:

```
class Color
{
public:
    virtual bool is_happy() = 0;
    virtual Color* rotate() = 0;
    virtual int intensity() = 0;

    static Color* const Red;
    static Color* const Green;
    static Color* const Blue;

    Color(Color const&) = delete;

private:
    Color(){}

    template<bool happiness, Color* const* rotation_result, int intensity_value>
    class Color_Generator;

    template<bool happiness, Color* const* rotation_result, int intensity_value>
    friend class Color_Generator;
};

template<bool happiness, Color* const* rotation_result, int intensity_value>
class Color::Color_Generator : public Color
{
public:
    bool is_happy()
    {
        return happiness;
    }

    Color* rotate()
    {
        return *rotation_result;
    }

    int intensity()
    {
        return intensity_value;
    }

    static Color_Generator<happiness, rotation_result, intensity_value> Instance;
};

template<bool happiness, Color* const* rotation_result, int intensity_value>
Color::Color_Generator<happiness, rotation_result, intensity_value>
Color::Color_Generator<happiness, rotation_result, intensity_value>::Instance;

Color* const Color::Red = &Color_Generator<true, &Green, 11>::Instance;
Color* const Color::Green = &Color_Generator<true, &Blue, 12>::Instance;
Color* const Color::Blue = &Color_Generator<false, &Red, 4>::Instance;

//==============
// Some usage follows

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Color* a = Color::Red;
    Color* b = Color::Green;
    Color* c = Color::Blue;

    std::cout << a->intensity() << std::endl;
    std::cout << b->is_happy() << std::endl;
    std::cout << (b->rotate() == c) << std::endl;
}
```

There are some more C++ features available to even further improve this code. For example, you might use virtual inheritance in order to split the definition of `is_happy`, `rotate` and `intensity` into their own 'facet' classes in the true spirit of C++.

Answer (score 2):

Two givens: if you want member functions (which seems
reasonable), then it must be a class; and things which differ
only in attributes (like `Red`, `Green` and `Blue`) should *not*
have different types.

It's not clear why you want to limit the number of colors to 3,
but in the end, this comes down to ensuring that you have
exactly 3 instances of your class, and no more.  The simplest
way of doing this is to make the constructor private, and make
the instances static members:

```
class Color
{
    Color( /* whatever parameters are needed */ );
public:
    static Color red;
    static Color green;
    static Color blue;
    //  ...
};
```

Users would then use Color::red, Color::green and Color::blue
(which has the added advantage that you could do something
similar with moods, and Mood::blue would not cause a naming
conflict).

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** simplified code a bit

You can implement it as base class `Color` which has three subclasses `Red`, `Green` and `Blue`, and has static constants `RED`, `GREEN` and `BLUE` respectively:

```
class Red;
class Green;
class Blue;

class Color;
typedef const Color* Color_t;

class Color {
    friend class Red;
    friend class Green;
    friend class Blue;

public:

    static Color_t RED;
    static Color_t GREEN;
    static Color_t BLUE;

    virtual std::string name() const = 0;

private:

    // prohibit instantiation of non-friend subclasses
    virtual ~Color() = default;

    static const Red RED_;
    static const Green GREEN_;
    static const Blue BLUE_;
};

class Red : public Color {
    friend class Color;
private:
    Red() {};  // prohibit instantiation other than by Color
    std::string name() const {return "Red";}
};

class Green : public Color {
    friend class Color;
private:
    Green() {};
    std::string name() const {return "Green";}
};

class Blue : public Color {
    friend class Color;
private:
    Blue() {};
    std::string name() const {return "Blue";}
};

const Red Color::RED_;
const Green Color::GREEN_;
const Blue Color::BLUE_;

Color_t Color::RED = &RED_;
Color_t Color::GREEN = &GREEN_;
Color_t Color::BLUE = &BLUE_;

int main() {
    Color_t c = Color::GREEN;
    c = Color::BLUE;
    if (c == Color::GREEN) {
        std::cout << c-> name() << " is green" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << c-> name() << " is not green" << std::endl;
    }

    // we can make collections of colors easily
    std::vector<Color_t> colors = { Color::RED, Color::RED, Color::GREEN, Color::BLUE, Color::GREEN };
    return 0;
}
```

[Here is the demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c741e3ac097daa0)

This is actually similar to how enums are implemented in Java.

Comment: I like this solution! But is it, to the best of your knowledge and judgement, the best solutions? Why is it better than the http://ideone.com/sQfUtf ?

Comment: @Herbert because here you have what you wanted - a class-like behavior, demonstraned by virtual function `name()`.

Comment: I guess the good thing is that I can append functionality in either the subclasses or the super class, avoiding switch-statements handling per-color behavior. However, how would I represent a list of red, green and blues like 'rgbrrrgbbbrrrbbrr' ?

Comment: @Herbert exactly, you don't have to write switch statements. You can make a list as follows: `std::vector<const Color*> colors = { Color::RED, Color::RED, Color::GREEN, Color::BLUE, Color::GREEN };`
`

Comment: I see, nice! Although a pity one needs to work with pointers to use standard containers!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60707/discussion-between-herbert-and-anton-savin).

Comment: @Herbert The basic problem here is that different colors are really different _values_ of the same type, and that you don't support copy (otherwise, you could end up with several instances).  You could easily define a `ColorWrapper` class, which acted like a pointer to a (static instance of a) color, but in the end: why?  If `Color` has value semantics, why not implement it as a value, with support for copy and assignment?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is an `enum` and functions that act on that `enum`, and a way of letting the world know that these functions and this `enum` belong together, then perhaps a `namespace` is exactly the tool for you.

```
namespace Color
{
enum EColor // or in C++11 use an enum class and set the underlying type to char or such
{
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE
};
bool IsHappy(const EColor & color);
int Intensity(const EColor & color);
EColor Rotate(const EColor & color);
}
```

You could just as easily make this a class with member functions since every function takes an `EColor` to work on, but using a namespace might make it easier for you to break apart the functionality into separate modules if perhaps not every user of `EColor` cares about that color's happiness, or you happen to have a bunch of functions that are related to `EColor` but do not require a single `EColor` as a parameter.